# Matlab get symbols from matrix to assign value

Tags: matlab, symbols

I am creating a matrix of symbols and I declare a function using them:

```
x = syms('x', [1 2]);
f = x(1) + x(2)
```

So x and f are:

```
x = [x1 x2];
f = x1 + x2
```

Now I want to give values to `x1` and `x2` in a for loop and evaluate `f`. But when I use:

```
x(1) = value;
```

then `x` becomes:

```
x = [1 x2]
```

and `x1` is lost, so I cannot evaluate `f`. How can I assign a value to `x1`, `x2`, ..., `xn` and then evaluate `f`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `subs` like the following:

```
subs(f,x1,value)
```

instead of replacing symbol of `x1` with a value.
You can see the details of the function [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html).

Comment: Thank you. I created a function with a for loop that everytime it reduces the function by replacing a value, using your suggestion.

Comment: Note that you can also replace all the values at the same time: `subs(f, x, [value1 value2]`